# Secondary menu header as parent page title

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

My secondary menu is set to be the second level of the main menu. How would I be able to make it so that secondary menu header as parent page title?

This is the code I'm using to print out the secondary menu:

```
   <?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
          'links' => $secondary_menu,
          'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'secondary-menu-links',
            'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
          ),
          'heading' => array(
            'text' => t('Secondary menu'),
            'level' => 'h2',
            'class' => array(),
          ),
        )); ?>
```

As you can see it is currently being defined by `'text' => t('Secondary menu'),` Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try the following code, using drupal's [drupal_get_title](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_title/7)():

```
print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
          'links' => $secondary_menu,
          'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'secondary-menu-links',
            'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
          ),
          'heading' => array(
            'text' => drupal_get_title(), // this is the only line I had to edit.
            'level' => 'h2',
            'class' => array(),
          ),
        ));
```

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: That only prints out the current page title. Which means if I am on a child/sub page it will print the child/sub-page's title instead of the parent. I have however found a modual which allows me to be able to do what I want - http://drupal.org/node/748022

Sorry for the delay in reply. I'm only working on this part-time